# Upgrade php 5.3 to php 5.4 linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

I have an Ubuntu server with many site inside.
This server is used:
- to test sites
- to create sites
- to store some sites of particular client

The version of php is 5.3 and I want to upgrade to php 5.4.

Into this server there is apache2 and phpmyadmin.

Is a good thing to upgrade to php 5.4?
Can I have some problem with my existing site inside the server?

How to upgrade the server?

What you advise to do? Update or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't advise that you touch your version of php because of this question: "How to upgrade the server?" If you don't know the how, it is likely you don't know the why either and at that point... If it is not broken you may not want to fix it. That handles the last bit of your question up front.

**Is it a good thing to upgrade?** As long as it doesn't break anything.

**Will it break anything?** maybe. We don't know what kind of code exists on the server(phpmyadmin is probably safe but I suspect you have more). In practice you are most likely safe, but if you don't know what's going on you should probably leave it alone.

**How to upgrade the server?** It's been awhile since I played with apt but... `apt-get upgrade php` There is a chance your repos won't have the latest versions. If that is the case and you **NEED** to upgrade... there are tutorials online... but you might consider bringing on a consultant.

Comment: a very bad notice.. I'd like to use some new feature of php 5.4 on our new site

Comment: It's your server, do what you will but my advice is: **ONLY** upgrade if the version you want to move to is part of the repositories for the version of Ubuntu you are using. If you are a masochist, download the php src, compile it, and install it where ever and however you want.

Comment: You don't need todo something so drastic like that, you just need to add the ppa from Ondrej (debian maintainer): https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable